# Rails save data from checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

i have the following form

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@software)  do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :softwarename, :collection => software_options, as: :check_boxes %>
```

And this helper.

```
module SoftwareHelper

def software_options
    ['7zip','SysInternals','Office','PDF-Creator']
end
end
```

My application controller looks like this

```
def software_params
    params.require(:software).permit(:softwarename => [])
end
```

And here is my software controller:

```
def new
    @software = Software.new
end

def create
    @software = Software.new(software_params)

    @software.save
    redirect_to @software
end
```

When I try to save the form input to my database (sqllite) i get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't cast Array to string
```

Do i have to convert the array to a string?

Comment: The `collection` option will make the data come through as an array.  So you will need to convert this array to whatever form you store the data in the database, which you don't specify.  How are you actually storing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving error as

```
TypeError: can't cast Array to string
```

because the attribute that you are trying to save i.e., `softwarename` is of type `String` in database and you are passing its value as an `Array` from the form (with checkboxes).

What you can do is mark `softwarename` attribute for serialization using `serialize` method, so that the Array passed as value of `softwarename` is converted to a String before saving it in database. This would also take care of deserialization from `String` to `Array` in case you are retrieving the attribute from database.

```
class Software < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :softwarename, Array  ## Add this line
  ## ...
end
```

Refer to [serialize method documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) for more details.